# While loop for multiple inputs

Tags: java

I understand that this may be a simple question with a simple answer but for some reason it is beyond me. My class is working in BlueJ right now and we are plotting points on a graph that we are creating with squares, right now I need to make the following prompt loop until a certain condition (x=-1) continue for as many inputs as the user sees fit.

```
public void plotPoints(Scanner keyboard)
{

            System.out.print("Enter an x and y coordinate: ");


            //Read x from user
            int x = keyboard.nextInt(); 

            //Read y from user
            int y = keyboard.nextInt();

            //Plot the point
            new Circle(x,y);
}
```

it is recommended that we use a while loop for this.

Comment: This is not javascript.

Comment: oh okay, just normal java?

Comment: Yes this is Java, not Javascript.

Comment: If you have to get as many input then the user has to iterate in inputting the parameters. So you should use a loop; `for` or `while`.

Comment: Refer to [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/) to learn about [while and do-while loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html). I would suggest do-while in this case since you want to perform the loop at least once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does the work.

```
public class PlotPoints {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        PlotPoints pp = new PlotPoints();
        pp.plotPoints(sc);
    }
    public void plotPoints(Scanner keyboard)
    {
        int x=1;
        while (x != -1) {

            System.out.print("Enter an x and y coordinate: ");


            //Read x from user
            x = keyboard.nextInt();

            //Read y from user
            int y = keyboard.nextInt();

            //Plot the point
            new Circle(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, I tried something very very similar to this just before posting this and it did not run correctly. Not sure what I did wrong, i no longer have the code for it. But I appreciate your reminder of the working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an infinite while or for loop with a break condition as below:

```
public List<Circle> plotPoints(Scanner keyboard){

    List<Circle> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

    while(true){ // for(;;) {

        System.out.println("Enter an x and y coordinate: ");

        System.out.println("Enter value for x: (x=-1 to exit)");
        //Read x from user
        int x = keyboard.nextInt(); 
        System.out.println("x =" + x);

        if(x == -1){
           System.out.println("Good bye!");
           break;
        }

        //Read y from user
        System.out.println("Enter value for y: ");
        int y = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("y = " + y);
        System.out.println("Plotting point (" + x + "," +  y + ")");

        //Plot the point            
        arrList.add(new Circle(x,y));
     }

     return arrList;

}
```

The code above gives the logic to get as many parameters as the user wishes to input. The method is suppose to return a collection of the plotted points so the array list `arrList` is there to collect all the plotted point. At first I thought you were trying to draw circles but that is not possible as you are not getting the value for the radius.