# How do i change my code so that if theres a second input it will add onto my histogram?

Tags: java

```
public class Histogram {
    private static Scanner input;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lettersInput = input.nextLine();
        lettersInput=lettersInput.toLowerCase();
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        int[] count = new int[alphabet.length()];
        for(int x = 0; x <  lettersInput.length();x++){
            int letter = alphabet.indexOf(lettersInput.charAt(x));
            if(letter < 0){
                continue;
            }
            count[letter]++;
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < count.length; x++){

            System.out.print(String.format("%s" + ":" +"%s", alphabet.charAt(x), new String(new char[count[x]]).replace('\0','*')));
            System.out.println();
            if(count[x]< 1) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

right now it only makes it accept one input of letters and if you want to put another set it makes a new histogram.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47150081/460557 essentially is just what you need.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept comeback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution: create a method like *makeHistogram()* that takes a string and prints the histogram for that (basically you just move some of your code from the main method into that new method).

Then you put a while loop into your main method. Within the body of that loop, you first ask the user for another line of text, and then you call the new method and pass that input to it.